Asymptotic Distribution of MLE of gaussian $N(\theta,\theta)$ using both delta method and fisher information
I was tasked with finding $\newcommand{\ml}[1]{\hat{#1}_{MLE}} \newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}} \newcommand{\pdv}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}} \ml{\theta}$ for $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, random i.i.d. samples where $\mu = \sigma^2 = \theta > 0$ and $\theta$ is an unknown parameter. I think I did so correctly, but then I was tasked with finding the fisher information based asymptotic distribution, and the delta-method based one, and I think I made some errors there as the results seem really close but don't converge. Can you please tell me whether my techniques are correct seeing as its my first time computing asymptotic distribution in either method?

my attempt - delta method

$$\ml\theta = \frac{-1+ \sqrt{1 + 4 (\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i^2)}}{2}$$
2. let's find the asymptomatic distribution of $\ml\theta$ using the delta method:
we'll define $Z_i = X_i^2$
$$\bar Z_n \triangleq \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i$$
we'll note that: $\E(Z_i) = \E(X_i^2) = \E(X)^2+\text{Var}(X) = \mu^2+\sigma^2$
$\text{Var}(Z_i) = \text{Var}(X_i^2) = \E(X_i^4)-\E(X_i^2)^2 = 3\sigma^4-(\mu^2+\sigma^2)^2 = 2\sigma^4 - \mu^4 - 2\mu^2\sigma^2$
via the CLT: $\bar Z_n \xrightarrow{d} N(\mu_{Z_i},\sigma^2_{Z_i}) =  N(\mu^2+\sigma^2,\frac{ 2\sigma^4 - \mu^4 - 2\mu^2\sigma^2}{n^2})$
if we define $$g(\bar Z) = \frac{-1+ \sqrt{1 + 4 (\bar Z)}}{2}$$then via the delta method:
$$g(\bar Z) \xrightarrow{d} N(g(\mu_{Z_i}),\frac{g'(\mu_{Z_i})^2\sigma_{Z_i}^2}{n})$$
computing the mean
$$g(\mu_{Z_i}) = \frac{-1+ \sqrt{1 + 4 (\mu^2+\sigma^2)}}{2}$$
and the variance:
$$g'(x) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+4x}} \cdot 4 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4x}}$$ $$\frac{g'(\mu_{Z_i})^2\sigma_{Z_i}^2}{n} = \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{1+4(\mu^2+\sigma^2)}(2\sigma^4 - \mu^4 - 2\mu^2\sigma^2)$$
since $g(\bar Z) = \ml{\theta}$, we know that the asymptotic distribution of the MLE estimator is:
$$\ml{\theta} \xrightarrow{d} N\left(\frac{-1+ \sqrt{1 + 4 (\mu^2+\sigma^2)}}{2},\frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{1+4(\mu^2+\sigma^2)}(2\sigma^4 - \mu^4 - 2\mu^2\sigma^2)\right)$$
We can substitute back $\mu = \sigma^2 = \theta$:
$$\begin{aligned} \frac{-1+ \sqrt{1 + 4 (\mu^2+\sigma^2)}}{2} &=\\ \frac{-1+ \sqrt{1 + 4 (θ^2+θ)}}{2} &= \\ \frac{-1+ \sqrt{(2\theta+1)^2}}{2} &=\\ θ \end{aligned}$$
which makes sense, since MLE estimators are asymptotically unbiased.
for the variance substituting it similarly nets us in the end:
$$\ml{\theta} \xrightarrow{d} N\left(θ,\frac{-θ^4+2\theta^2-2\theta^3}{n(1+4θ^2+4θ)}\right)$$
which isn't the neatest expression...

fisher information attempt
let's find the asymptotic distribution using Fisher information:
let's start by computing $I_n(\theta) = n I (\theta)$
We know that $I(\theta) = -\E(\pdv{^2}{^2\theta} l(\theta))$
from the previous calculation we got:
$$\begin{aligned}\pdv{l_n(\theta)}{\theta} &= \frac{1}{\theta} - \frac{R_n^2}{\theta^2} + \frac{\theta \cdot (-2)(\bar X_n - \theta) - (\bar X_n - \theta)^2 \cdot 1}{\theta^2} \\ &=\frac1\theta + \frac{-R_n^2-[\bar X_n+\theta](\bar{X_n}-\theta)}{\theta^2} \\ & = \frac1\theta+ \frac{-(R_n^2+X_n^2)}{\theta^2}+1 \\ &=\frac1\theta-\frac{1}{n\theta^2}\sum X_i^2 +1 \\ \partial^2_{\theta} l (\theta) &=\frac{-1}{\theta^2} + \frac{2}{n\theta^3} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \\-\E[ \partial^2_{\theta} l (\theta)] &= \frac{1}{\theta^2} - \frac{2}{ n\theta^3}  n(\mu^2+\sigma^2) = I(\theta) \end{aligned}$$
where in the last step we used the expectation value we calculated previously.
so we know:
$$\newcommand{\pdv}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}} I_n(\theta) = n \cdot (\frac{1}{\theta^2} - \frac{2}{\theta^3} (\theta^2+\theta))$$ due to asymptotic normality we get that
$$\ml\theta \xrightarrow{d} N[\theta,I_n(\theta)^{-1}] = N\left[\theta, \frac1n \frac{\theta^2}{2\theta-1}\right]$$
are my attempts correct? I think I must've gotten something wrong in the delta method, but I'm not sure I have conceptually understood them the best...
thanks!

coin dropped - will post a solution within a week
